# escape character not convert properly when calling webservice in iPhone app...?

Tags: iphone, json, web-services, html-escape-characters

I'm using JSON web service to collect data and display in my `UITableView` cell. My problem is when I try to call my web service, if the data has characters like `&` it gives me `&amp;`.
When I try to store this JSON data in `NSDictionary` and after that display in `UITableView` cell it appear as it is.

Eg. if data is `Chris & Priscilla` originally it retrieves as `Chris &amp; Priscilla` and same shows in my cell. I want to display it as `Chris & Priscilla` and not `Chris &amp; Priscilla`.

It displays properly in browser.

I can't find what I missed.

```
    NSError *error = nil;
NSString *strUrl = @"MY-WEBSERVICE-URL";
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:strUrl];
NSString *returnText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
txt.text = returnText;
```

Comment: Could you expand on what you expect to see vs what you're seeing in the browser? At the moment, you only say it shows as Chris & Priscilla  as you originally entered, what did you expect it to show? Chris %40 Priscilla or something else?

Comment: Smriti Yadav-you can find code now from which I got this issue.Zhang when i try the same url in browser it give me proper string with & but when I call through above code it give me `&amp;`

Comment: Anyone have the same issue, What is the wrong can anyone reply

Answer (score 0):

Usually HTML unescaping is done adding a category to NSString. There are many examples, i.e. here: http://google-toolbox-for-mac.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString+HTML.h. 
Particularly, have a look at  
(NSString *)gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML;

Comment: I have understood that you need to convert escaped characters into their original representation (e.g. &amp; -> &).
I can read this in the comment for the method I mentioned:
/// Get a string where internal characters that are escaped for HTML are unescaped 
//
///  For example, '&amp;' becomes '&'